# How to call COM function from PHP with OLE_COLOR as an argument?

Tags: php, com, colors, ole

I am trying to call a COM object from PHP using the COM interop extension. One function requires an OLE_COLOR as an argument? Is there any way to pass this kind of value from PHP?

I have tried passing a simple integer value with no success.

```
$this->oBuilder->Font->Color = 255;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP can define the constants the COM exposes automatic.

set_ini('[com.autoregister-typelib](http://php.net/manual/en/com.configuration.php#ini.com.autoregister-typelib)', true);

or by hand

[com_load_typelib](http://php.net/manual/en/function.com-load-typelib.php)($typelib_name);

But if the OLE_COLOR is a **object** instead of an integer, string or other primitive
using constants (or integers) won't work.

```
$Color = new COM('ColorClass');
$Color->set_color_function($red, $green, $blue);
```

Or something similar will.

Answer (score 0):

When I've called COM functions from PHP, I just passed them in the call.  So my old code has:

```
$myComObject = new COM("MY_COM_OBJECT");
$myComObject->Myfunction( myVar1, myVar2, 'my string var');
```